# Best way to verify user identity

Tags: users, verification

I'm going to build eCommerce type website in USA where I need to find the true identity of the user when he/she create account.

Because some people to bad things for example upload fake product and when someone come one meet up address they robe it or something like that. So I want to avoid this kind of situation. User can easily create account of website and you don't have any way to track them. Suppose person goes to court and told that he robed by someone how they find that person because they don't know anything about that person.

So I decided to find the true identity of the users.

1. Phone verification will not work because mostly mobile numbers don't have the bio-metric verification are they?
2. Credit card verifications just charge a little amount to verify the Credit card. But they can use virtual cards so how we can manage it?
3. Companies like Stripe only charge a little amount from credit cards and approve if the card is valid but they don't provide any information about the user. is there any way to get information?
4. SSN number also doesn't work, you can easily add someone SSN and create an account. How will you verify that this is the same person which has the SSN ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend you a third party company to do the ID check. They are doing KYC and AML to check the true users' identity. https://www.au10tix.com/

Another way you can do this inhouse is to ask the user to do open webcam and do a photo with a generated code written on a piece of paper.

Comment: is there no other way

Comment: I think these are all the options you have for now. There are some interesting projects out there using blockchain to validate identity but they are still being tested from what I know. 

Here is a link if you want to read more about them:
https://www.disruptordaily.com/blockchain-use-cases-identity-management/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it's best if you outsource it to a 3rd party verifier instead of building something cumbersome in-house. There are a ton of options available in the market like Passbase or Onfido, AuthBridge, etc., These guys all have elegant APIs that do the job wonderfully well. Seamless integration and get the job done easily.

Personally, I went with [Passbase](https://passbase.com/) for a micro crypto trading app that I’m building in stealth. My market is highly competitive and at the same time, identity verification is very crucial.

I have to verify my users AND make sure that the verification is quick, simple, and seamless.

With Passbase, my users can sign up and get verified in just a couple of clicks from their browser. Just upload a selfie-and they are onboarded.

I have to say, I was a tad bit worried about the authenticity but then again, they seem to be doing pretty well. So go for it, don’t think twice."

Answer (score 1):

I would delegate ID to check by integrating 3rd party services like Apple Pay which not only verifies identity using biometrics but also takes care of handling payment. It would also make it easy for users to pay (those who use such services) using Apple devices and you won't have to store sensitive data on your servers.